# Find the farthest rotation matrix in $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ from a given matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Consider the norm $\| A \| = \sqrt{\mathrm{tr}(AA^t)}$. It's easy to see that $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ is a compact subspace of $3 \times 3$ matrices in the topology induced by this norm because $\mathrm{O}(3)$ is compact and $SO(3)$ being the inverse image of $\{1\}$ under the map $\mathrm{det}$ is a closed subset of $\mathrm{O}(n)$. So, it makes sense to talk about the nearest rotation and the farthest rotation matrix from a given matrix. The former one, the nearest one, has been discussed online and I could find a lot of information about it by Googling. However, the farthest rotation matrix was not discussed. Out of curiosity, is it possible to find the farthest rotation matrix to a given matrix?

I tried to solve the problem using Lagrange multipliers but I didn't know how to proceed because I'm not good at matrix calculus.

Comment: I noticed that you set $\Vert A \Vert = \text{tr}(AA^T)$; is this what you really meant? most authors use $\Vert A \Vert^2 = \text{tr}(AA^T)$.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm.   Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis  You're absolutely right. Sorry for the typo. It won't be a good generalization of the Euclidean distance on vectors if we don't have the square root in the definition. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: After reading user1551's answer it's not clear to me: Are you asking about the furthest element in $SO(3)$ from another element of $SO(3)$, or from a general matrix?

Comment: @Travis I'm asking about the furthest element in $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ from a general $3 \times 3$ matrix $M$. $M$ could even be a non-invertible matrix. I still haven't had time to read the answers. I've been at the university the whole day today. :(

Comment: Ah, I see---the first two answers (Jacky's and mine) assumed the question was about the furthest element from another matrix in $SO(3)$, maybe because, as user1551 points out, the problem of finding the furthest matrix from a general matrix is so similar to that of finding the nearest matrix: One is still looking for a critical point of the objective function, just a max rather than a min. In particular, the first statement of my hint only applies to matrices $A$ for which multiplication $A$ preserves $||\,\cdot\,||$, i.e., $A \in O(n)$.

Comment: @Travis  Yes. I'm sorry for the confusion. But even so, your answer is still valuable I think. I was planning to read it as soon as I got home. You don't need to remove it. Just mention that it addresses a different problem and it's fine.

Comment: In that case I'll restore it and add a note---cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding the farthest matrix is actually not that different from finding the nearest matrix. The same techniques are used. It's just the conclusion that is different.

In general, suppose $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ and we want to maximise or minimise the Frobenius norm $\|A-R\|_F$ subject to $R\in SO(n,\mathbb R)$. Let $A=USV^T$ be a singular value decomposition and let $Q=U^TRV$. The value of the objective function is then equal to $\|S-Q\|_F$. By considering the squared Frobenius norm, we see the optimisation of $\|A-R\|_F$ is equivalent to the optimisation of $\operatorname{tr}(SQ)$.

Suppose $Q$ is a global optimiser of $\operatorname{tr}(SQ)$. The usual calculus argument shows that $SQ$ must be symmetric, i.e. $SQ=(SQ)^T=Q^TS$. Hence $S^2=(SQ)(Q^TS)=(Q^TS)(SQ)=(Q^TSQ)^2$ and (by the uniqueness of positive semidefinite square root) $S=Q^TSQ$. Thus $S$ commutes with $Q$ and the eigenspace corresponding to each eigenvalue of $S$ is an invariant subspace of $Q$.

For each nonzero eigenvalue of $S$, since the restriction of $S$ on the corresponding eigenspace is just a scaling operator, the condition that $SQ$ is symmetric means that the restriction of $Q$ on that eigenspace is symmetric too. If $S$ has a zero eigenvalue, since the restriction of $Q$ on the null space of $S$ does not affect the value of $\operatorname{tr}(SQ)$, we can also assume that the restriction of $Q$ on that null space is symmetric.

In other words, there exists a global optimiser of $\operatorname{tr}(SQ)$ such that $Q$ is symmetric. Therefore, by simultaneous orthogonal diagonalisation, we may assume that $Q$ is diagonal. As $Q$ is also real orthogonal, its diagonal entries must be $\pm1$.

The argument up to this point is the same no matter we want to maximise or minimise $\|A-R\|_F$. With the observation that the optimal $Q$ can be taken to be a diagonal orthogonal matrix, it is now obvious that the global maximum of $\|A-R\|_F$ subject to $R=UQV^T\in SO(n,\mathbb R)$ is given by
\begin{aligned}
R&=-U\operatorname{diag}\left(1,\ldots,1,\det(-UV^T)\right)V^T,\\
\|A-R\|_F&=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(s_i+1)^2+\left(s_n+\det(-UV^T)\right)^2}.
\end{aligned}
where $s_1\ge s_2\ge\cdots\ge s_n\ge0$ are the singular values of $A$. In contrast, the global minimum of $\|A-R\|_F$ subject to $R\in SO(n,\mathbb R)$ is given by
\begin{aligned}
R&=U\operatorname{diag}\left(1,\ldots,1,\det(UV^T)\right)V^T,\\
\|A-R\|_F&=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(s_i-1)^2+\left(s_n-\det(UV^T)\right)^2}.
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 3):

Since @Travis gave an elegant solution using geometry then we will solve the problem using Lagrange multiplier. WLOG,let us consider the function $f:M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
\begin{align}
f(A) = \|I-A\|^2
\end{align}
subjected to the system of constraints
\begin{align}
g(A)=A^TA -I = 0.
\end{align}
Note that we are $f$ is a $n^2$-variable function and there are $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ constraint equation (i.e. $6$ when $n=3$).

More explicitly, we have the constraint equations
\begin{align}
g_{ij}(A)=a_{i1}a_{1j}+a_{i2}a_{2j}+a_{i3}a_{3j} - \delta_{ij}=0 \ \ \ \text{ for }\ \   1\leq i\leq j \leq n.
\end{align}

Now, we can write down the Lagrange function
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(A,\lambda) = \|I-A\|^2-\sum_{i, j}\lambda_{ij} g_{ij}(A) 
\end{align}
where $\lambda$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix. Note that we can rewrite $\mathcal{L}$ in the form
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(A,\lambda) = \|I-A\|^2-\operatorname{tr}(\lambda^T g(A)).
\end{align}
Finally, observe
\begin{align}
\nabla_{A, \lambda}\mathcal{L} =& 
\begin{pmatrix}
2I-A-A^T-(\lambda+\lambda^T)A^T\\
g(A)
\end{pmatrix}\\ =& 
\begin{pmatrix}
2I-A-A^T-2\lambda A^T\\
A^TA-I
\end{pmatrix}
=\mathbf{0}.
\end{align}

Solving the algebra yields
\begin{align}
A^2-2A+I+2\lambda = \mathbf{0}
\end{align}
or equivalently
\begin{align}
&A^2-2A=(A^T)^2-2A^T\\
&\implies \ \ A^T = A^3-2A^2+2I\\
&\implies \ \ A^4-2A^3+2A-I=(A-I)^3(A+I)=\mathbf{0} \\
&\implies \text{ eigenvalues of $A$ equals } \pm 1
\end{align}
In particular, we have that 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}A \geq
\begin{cases}
-n & \text{ if } n \text{ even},\\
-(n-2) & \text{ if } n \text{ odd}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Note that
\begin{align}
f(A)=&\ \operatorname{tr}[(I-A)^T(I-A)]\\
=&\ \operatorname{tr}(2I-A-A^T)= 2(n-\operatorname{tr}(A))\\
\leq&\ \begin{cases}
4n & \text{ if } n \text{ even},\\
4(n-1) & \text{ if } n \text{ odd}.
\end{cases}.
\end{align}
Moreover, $f$ attains the maximum value. In the case $n$ even, we can take $A=-I$. In the case $n$ odd, we take the matrix
\begin{align}
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -I_{(n-1)\times(n-1)}
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

Comment: @Travis Good point.

Comment: +1 This is quite nice!

Comment: Thanks. How do you make sure that $\det(A) = +1$ and it's not equal to $-1$?

Comment: @stressedout  Up to the point of showing the eigenvalues are $\pm 1$, I did not impose the condition $\det(A)=1$. However, afterward, when you try to find a lower bound for $\operatorname{tr}A$  you will need to further restrict yourself to $\det(A) =1$.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** OP has clarified since this answer was posted that they are interested in finding for any matrix $A \in M(n, \Bbb R)$ the matrix in $SO(3)$ from which it is farthest. This answer addresses the special case of the problem when $A$ itself is in $SO(3)$. See [user1551's post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2985857/155629) for a nice solution that covers the more general case.

**Hint** Since multiplication by orthogonal matrices preserves $||\cdot||$, if $B$ is the matrix in $SO(n)$ furthest from a given matrix $A \in SO(n)$, then $B A^{-1}$ is the matrix in $SO(n)$ furthest from $I$, and vice versa.

Thus, it suffices to find which matrix $C \in SO(n)$ achieves the maximum of
$$d(I, C)^2 = ||I - C||^2 = \operatorname{tr}[(I - C)^T (I - C)] = \operatorname{tr}(2 I - C - C^T) = 2 (n - \operatorname{tr} C) ,$$
that is, we want to minimize $\operatorname{tr} C$.

> Since $C \in SO(n)$, the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ must satisfy $1 = \det C = \prod \lambda_i$. Likewise, since $C$ is real, any nonreal eigenvalues come in complex conjugate pairs. So for $n = 3$, the eigenvalues of $C$ are $e^{i \theta}, e^{-i \theta}, 1$ for some $\theta$, and so $\operatorname{tr} C = 1 + 2 \cos \theta$. This is minimized for $\theta = -1$, that is, eigenvalues $-1, -1, 1$. But the orthogonal matrices with these eigenvalues are exactly the rotations by a half-turn about some axis---there is one such rotation for each axis, so there are an $\Bbb R P^2$'s worth of these---and for these matrices $d(I, C) = 2 \sqrt{2}$. Similar arguments give a sharp upper bound $d(I, C) \leq 2 \sqrt{2 \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor}$ for all $n$.