# How to calculate $R=M(M^tM)^{-1/2}$ when one of the eigenvalues of $M^tM$ is $0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, rotations, matrix-decomposition

Suppose that I want to calculate the closest rotation in $SO(n)$ to an $n \times n$ matrix $M$. It can be shown by geometric arguments that $R = M(M^tM)^{-1/2}$. However, this requires that we can calculate $(M^tM)^{-1/2}$. This is easy when $M^tM$ has a spectral decomposition with non-zero eigenvalues. But what if one of the eigenvalues is $0$?

**Edit:**

Here's the geometric argument that I mentioned:

Suppose that we are in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$. Consider $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ as a subset of this space. We know that the tanget to $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ at $I$ consists of anti-symmetric matrices. We can shift the tangent space to other points by left multiplication. So, given $M$ in the ambient space, I want to project it on $\mathrm{SO}(n)$. On the other hand, we know that anti-symmetric matrices and symmetric matrices are orthogonal complements of each other in the ambient space with respect to the inner product given by $<A,B> = \mathrm{tr}(A^tB)$. Consider the set $\{RA: A\text{  is anti-symmetric. } \}$. For any $A$, $M-R$ must be orthogonal to $RA$:

$$\mathrm{tr}((RA)^t(R-M)) = 0$$
$$\mathrm{tr}(A^tR^tR-A^tR^tM) = 0$$
$$\mathrm{tr}(A^t(I-R^tM)) = 0$$

Hence, $I-R^tM$ is a symmetric matrix. Therefore, $R^tM$ is symmetric and we have $R^tM = S$, or equivalently $M=RS$. Now write the spectral decomposition for $M^tM$. Note that $M^tM = S^tR^tRS = S^2$. Hence, $S = (M^tM)^{1/2}$. Finally, $R = M(M^tM)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Why would $R\in SO(n)$ rather than $O(n)$ in your $R=M(M^tM)^{-1/2}$?

Comment: @user10354138  That's a good question. I suppose that if $\det$ is equal to $-1$, we can swap rows to fix it. But the geometric argument clearly showed that it belonged to $SO(n)$. I can add my understanding of the geometric argument here. But I might not be able to recover all the details. I can give it a try if you want.

Comment: @user10354138  I added the details of the geometric argument for you. Now it's clear that $R$ is in $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ because it is the projection of $M$ on $\mathrm{SO}(n)$.

Comment: You only have $R^tM$ is symmetric, not necessarily positive semidefinite.  So you can't conclude $S=(M^tM)^{1/2}$ from $S^2=M^tM$.

Comment: @user10354138  Do the eigenvalues of a PSD matrix have to be positive? I don't know anything about PSD matrices. Can this argument be saved?

Comment: Eigenvalues of PSD matrices are nonnegative (could be 0).  The negative eigenvalues are always going to be a possibility so we only get $M$ times an inverse square root of $M^tM$ in order to stay in $SO(n)$.  If you don't mind going to $O(n)$, then we can take $(M^tM)^{-1/2}$ and recover $R$ as the orthogonal factor in the polar decomposition of $M$ (assuming $M$ is invertible so $R$ is unique).

Comment: @user10354138 Could you please extend your comment into a complete answer? Also, how do you want to take $(M^tM)^{-1/2}$ when $M^tM$ is not invertible? (it has a $0$ eigenvalue).

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $R\in SO(n)$. Suppose $M$ is invertible. Then $(M^TM)^{-1/2}$ is positive definite. Hence $\det(R)$ have the same sign as $\det(M)$, which can be negative. At any rate, regardless of whether $\det(M)$ is +ve, -ve or zero, in my answer to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2985857), I have shown that the closest matrix (w.r.t. Frobenius norm) in $SO(n)$ to $M$ is given by $R=U\operatorname{diag}(1,\ldots,1,\det(UV^T))V^T$, where $M=USV^T$ is a SVD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You end up with $M^TM=S^TS=S^2$ and $M=RS$. This does not imply $S=(M^TM)^{1/2}$, it could also hold $S=-(M^TM)^{1/2}$.

Now take the singular value decomposition of $M$
$$
M = U\Sigma V^T,
$$
which implies the spectral decomposition of $M^TM$:
$$
M^TM = V\Sigma^2V^T.
$$
Let $W$ be a diagonal matrix with $W^2=\Sigma^2$. Then all matrices $S:=VWV^T$ satisfy $S^2=M^TM$. It remains to compute $R$. The equation $M=RS$ is equivalent to
$$
U\Sigma  = R VW.
$$
Let $i$ be such that the singular value $\sigma_i$ is positive. Then $\sigma_i U_i = w_iR V_i $, i.e., $R$ maps the vector $V_i$ to $\pm U_i$.
This specifies $R$ on $\ker M$.
If $M$ is not invertible, $R$ has to be completed to be in $SO(n)$. The choice of the square root $W$ is essential to get $\det(R)>0$.

There are many degrees of freedom in the construction: non-uniqueness of the SVD, the construction of $W$ up to even-number of sign-changes, the definition of $R$ on the kernel of $M$.

These considerations seems to compute stationary points only. Hence, the matrices $R$ constructed like this, are candidates. I do not know how to prove optimality for some/all of them.

Uniqueness cannot be expected: If $M=0$ then all matrices of $SO(n)$ are solutions.